# Throw WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat using Powermock and Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I'm using Springboot and junit, I want to use Powermock to mock static class, after added Powermock the unit test runs well through IntelliJ IDEA, but when i run `mvn test` under terminal, it throws **ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server\n   Unable to start embedded Tomcat**

My base test class :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = WebApplication.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore( {"javax.management.*", "javax.net.*", "javax.crypto.*"})
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.rolls"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class ApplicationTest {
    ...test
}
```

test class:

```
@Slf4j
@PrepareForTest(ClientCache.class)
public class RuleServiceTest extends ApplicationTest {


    @Mock
    private IClient iClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClientCache.class);
    }

    ...test
}
```

related maven `pom.xml`:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

```
        <!--   mock class    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Error run `mvn test`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ dq-web ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.rolls.ApplicationTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 36.015 s - in com.rolls.ApplicationTest
[INFO] Running com.rolls.common.utils.DateUtilTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.619 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.rolls.common.utils.DateUtilTest
[ERROR] com.rolls.common.utils.DateUtilTest.testGetFormattedDate1  Time elapsed: 0.618 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5b6afa58]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5b6afa58]
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
...
[ERROR] com.rolls.service.impl.RuleServiceTest.testListNotIn  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@795c941b]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@795c941b]
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
```

Seems `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` couldn't start springboot embeded tomcat, but to use Powermock, i need to run with it.

**Question:** anyone know how to integrate ***Powermock*** with ***Springboot***?

Comment: Just as an FYI that might help you to reduce the complexity for your test setup: Since version 3.4.0 [Mockito now also supports mocking static methods](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/). This way you could get rid of PowerMock and only use dependencies of the [Spring Boot Starter Test](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-with-spring-boot-starter-test/).

Comment: @rieckpil, after changed to Mockito 3.4.6, mock runs well but it seems skipped my code  and return mock value directly.

Comment: "seems skipped my code and return mock value directly" I don't get what you mean by this. Can you update your question with the code example that uses the static mocking feature of Mockito?

Comment: @rieckpil, I updated my answer, it's my mistake, Mockito works well, thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: I changed to use Mockito 3.4.6 instead of PowerMock**

See my pseudocode as below:

The target method i want to test

```
public String paramReplace(String type) {
   ...code here
   IClient client = ClientCache.getClient(type);
   client.execute();
   ...code here
}
```

```
public ClientCache {
   public static getClient(String type) {
      ...code here
      return client;
   } 
}
```

```
public Client {
   public String execute() {
     ...code here
     return "a";
   }
}
```

I want to test method `paramReplace()`, inner this method, i need to mock `ClientCache.getClient()`(a static method) and `client.execute()`.

My test class:

```
@Slf4j
public class JobParamReplaceTest extends ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    public JobParamReplace jobParamReplace;
    @Mock
    private IClient iClient;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
//        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClientCache.class);
       
//        iClient = Mockito.mock(IClient.class);
        MockedStatic<ClientCache> clientCache = Mockito.mockStatic(ClientCache.class);
        clientCache.when(() -> ClientCache.getClient(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(iClient);
//        Mockito.when(iClient.executeQuery(Mockito.any(ISourceDTO.class), Mockito.any(SqlQueryDTO.class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>());
        Mockito.when(iClient.executeQuery(Mockito.any(ISourceDTO.class), Mockito.any(SqlQueryDTO.class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testParamReplace() throws Exception {
        String sql_res = jobParamReplace.paramReplace("a");
        Assert.assertTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(sql_res));
    }
}
```

base test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = WebApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dtstack"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class ApplicationTest {

}
```

My maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Summary:**
Use `@Mock` to mock non-static method, and use `Mockito.mockStatic(ClientCache.class)` to mock static method